# How do I run a piece of C code through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, c, parsing

I have a piece of HTML/JS code that runs on a local server. When the server is started by the user, I want to have a parser I have written (in C) parse through a file. The parser works fine on its own. It looks through a text file in a custom format and outputs its data to a `struct`. The input looks like this:

```
MOVIENAME: [ACTOR1, ACTOR2 (OPTIONAL), ACTOR3 (OPTIONAL)], DIRECTOR, YEAR, GENRE
```

It stores it in a `struct` that looks like this:

```c
typedef char* spg_person;
typedef spg_person spg_actor;
typedef spg_person spg_director;
typedef char* spg_genre;
typedef char* spg_tag;
typedef int spg_year;

typedef struct _movie {
    char* title;
    spg_actor* actor;
    spg_genre genre;
    spg_year year;
    spg_director director;
} movie;
```

I *have* heard of JSON files, but I'm not sure how convert.

Thanks

Comment: To clarify, do you need to convert your C parser into a javascript parser?

Comment: @GrafiCode I want to convert my C parser **output** to something JavaScript can use.

Comment: Do you already know how to "send" it to your JavaScript?

Comment: How would the resulting output of [serializing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) the data held by the program differ from the formatted data in the file in the first place? Do you specifically want to have the C program [translate the file into JSON](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON)?

Comment: @caTS Not yet. That's part of what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @oka yes, translating into JSON seems to be what I'm looking for.